# Can a positive definite second order elliptic operator over an unbounded domain give rise to a compact semigroup?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $A$ denote some positive definite second order elliptic operator which is defined over $L^2(\Omega)$ with domain $D(A) = H^{2m}(\Omega) \cap H^{m}_{0}(\Omega)$. Here $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $R^m$. Assume that the coefficient functions of $A$ are nice enough, then it can be shown that the semigroup generated by $A$ is compact.

Now what if $\Omega$ is $[0, \infty)$? Is it possible that $A$ can still generate compact semigroup, if replacing the function spaces in the bounded case by some weighted function spaces? If so, are there any references please?

Comment: By second order do you mean only second order terms? Otherwise $-\Delta+V$ with $V$ unbounded and sufficiently nice fits the bill.

Comment: @MaoWao Hi, thank you for the comments! Indeed, at this stage, the operator could be general. Could you please be more specific? Like what kind of function space your operator would act on? Any references please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ be any domain, bounded or unbounded. If $(e^{-tA})$ is ultracontractive, i.e., $e^{-tA}$ maps $L^2(\Omega)$ into $L^\infty(\Omega)$ for $t>0$ and $V\in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ is nonnegative and $\{x\in \Omega|V(x)\leq M\}$ has finite measure for every $M>0$, then $(e^{-t(A+V)})$ is compact in $L^2(\Omega)$. This is Theorem 1 in Simon. *Schrödinger Operators with Purely Discrete Spectrum*.

For example, the Dirichlet Laplacian on any domain generates an ultracontractive semigroup. On $\mathbb R^n$, this can be seen from the explicit formula for $(e^{t\Delta})$, and for general domains this follows from a comparison principle. Also, if $A$ satisfies the Gagliardo-Nirenberg-Sobolev inequality
$$
\|u\|_{p^\ast}\leq C\langle Au,u\rangle^{1/2}
$$
for some $p^\ast>2$, then $(e^{-tA})$ is ultracontractive. In particular, if $A$ is an elliptic operator in divergence form
$$
Au=\sum_{j,k}\partial_j(a_{jk}\partial_ku)
$$
with coefficients $a_{j,k}\in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega)$ with $a_{jk}=a_{kj}$ and $\sum_{j,k}a_{jk}\xi_j\xi_k\geq \lambda\sum_{j}\xi_j^2$ for some $\lambda>0$, then $(e^{-tA})$ is ultracontractive.

A note on the domains: The domain of such operators is best described by the form method. In the case of the Laplacian the quadratic form associated with $-\Delta+V$ is given by
\begin{align*}
D(q_{-\Delta+V})&=\left\{u\in H^1_0(\Omega):\int_\Omega V|u|^2\,dx<\infty\right\}\\
q_{-\Delta+V}(u,v)&=\int _\Omega(\nabla u\cdot\nabla v+Vuv)\,dx,\;u,v\in D(q_{-\Delta+V}).
\end{align*}
Then
$$
D(-\Delta+V)=\{u\in D(q_{-\Delta+V}):\exists v\in L^2(\Omega)\,\forall w\in D(q_{-\Delta+V})\colon q_{-\Delta+V}(u,w)=\langle v,w\rangle_2\}.
$$
In the case of general elliptic operators in divergence form as described above, one has to replace $H^1_0(\Omega)$ by the form domain of $A$ (with Dirichlet boundary conditions), everything else stays the same. I won't go into details here, suffice it to say that if the coefficient matrix is uniformly bounded, then the form domain of $A$ is simply $H^1_0(\Omega)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Please allow to study it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! May I ask one more question please? Assume that the coefficient matrix is uniformly bounded, as you mentioned in the solution, why the domain is just $H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ instead of the intersection of it with $H^{2}(\Omega)$? Thank you!

Comment: I was talking about the form domain, not the domain of the operator. It is not so easy to directly describe the domain of $A+V$ given the domains of $A$ and $V$, but the form domain of $A+V$ is simply the intersection of the form domains of $A$ and $V$. From there you go to the domain of $A+V$ as described in my answer.